# Iteratively find all lines starting with X and move above next line starting with Y

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, awk, text-processors

I have a file like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Consectetur adipiscing elit.
MATCH1 Quis autem vel!
Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
MATCH1 Eum iure reprehenderit?
MATCH2 Qui in ea voluptate
Ut enim ad minim veniam.
Quis nostrud exercitation
TARGET
Sed ut perspiciatis unde.
MATCH1 Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas?
MATCH2 Sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit.
Omnis iste natus error sit.
Voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium
MATCH1 Ut enim ad minima veniam.
Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam
TARGET
Ut enim ad minima veniam.
```

How would I find all lines that start with `MATCH` (there can be one or many, but grouped together if there is more than one) and move them above the *next* occurrence of `TARGET` (always the same word, only one occurrence at a time), and iteratively repeat this process all the way down the file? The processed file would like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Consectetur adipiscing elit.
Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam.
Quis nostrud exercitation
MATCH1 Quis autem vel!
MATCH1 Eum iure reprehenderit?
MATCH2 Qui in ea voluptate
TARGET
Sed ut perspiciatis unde.
Omnis iste natus error sit.
Voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium
Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam
MATCH1 Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas?
MATCH2 Sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit.
MATCH1 Ut enim ad minima veniam.
TARGET
Ut enim ad minima veniam.
```

Any GNU/Linux commands are fine, preferably not `vi` or Emacs.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: @Toto, nothing yet, don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` with its "hold space" functionality seems good for the job.

```
<file sed '
   /^MATCH/ {H;d}
   /^TARGET$/ {H;s/.*//;x;s/\n//}
   '
```

It works like this:

- Any line of input that doesn't start with `MATCH` and doesn't consist of `TARGET` triggers no explicit commands and gets printed because it's the default behavior upon reaching the end of a script.
- A line that starts with `MATCH`

  - gets appended to the hold space (`H`);
  - next the pattern space is deleted and a new cycle starts (next line is read, the script starts over) without printing anything (`d`).
- A line that consists of `TARGET` triggers the following:

  - The line itself gets appended to the hold space (`H`). At this moment the hold space holds an empty line (because its initially empty content became an empty line after the fist `H`), zero or more lines with `MATCH` and exactly one line with `TARGET`.
  - The whole pattern space is replaced by nothing (`s/.*//`).
  - The pattern space and the hold space are swapped (`x`). At this moment the hold space is empty (ready to collect `MATCH`es anew) and the pattern space contains an empty line, few `MATCH`es maybe and one `TARGET`.
  - The unwanted empty line in the pattern space is just a newline character at the very beginning. It needs to be removed and this is what the next `s` does.
  - Then the script continues and the end of it is reached. The pattern space gets printed because it's the default behavior upon reaching the end.

So basically `MATCH`es are collected in the hold space and printed upon `TARGET`.

Notes:

- `^MATCH` means `MATCH` must be at the very beginning of the line. `MATCH` with leading spaces (or tabs etc.) won't match. `^TARGET$` requires no leading nor trailing spaces (or tabs etc.). If this is not right, adjust these patterns.
- `MATCH`es are collected even if not grouped together.
- `MATCH`(es) occurring after the last `TARGET` (or if there is no `TARGET` at all) will not be printed because there is no `TARGET` that would trigger printing the hold space that collected them.